How dense are (very but not extremely) smooth numbers? Can they be found in most (not very) short intervals?
An integer is said to be $y$-smooth if it has no prime factors $>y$. Let $y$ be "medium sized", meaning $(\log x)^{1+\epsilon} < y < \exp((\log x)^{2/3})$ or so. (Why this range of values? See the note below.)
Can one show that, for a positive proportion of all $x<n\leq 2x$, there is a $y$-smooth number within distance $x^{0.99}$ (say) of $n$?
Bonus points if you can replace "a $y$-smooth number" by "several $y$-smooth numbers".

Note: There is a rich literature on smooth numbers that I know only very superficially, but it seems to me it centers on larger $y$, for which one can give asymptotics for the number of smooth numbers in short intervals. A case in point is Theorem 5.2 in Hildebrand-Tenenbaum's Integers without large prime factors (which seems to cover roughly $y>\exp((\log x)^{2/3})$, if I am reading it correctly). I'm requiring $y>(\log x)^{1+\epsilon}$ because smooth numbers are very sparse otherwise (see Cor. 1.3 in Hildebrand-Tenenbaum).


Theorem 5.2 in that survey does not give any asymptotic result (or even a lower bound) when $z=x^{0.99}$, this is due to the second error term $O(\Psi(x,y)R_{\epsilon})$. 2. After Theorem 5.4 in the survey, the authors mention the work of Harman ("Short intervals containing numbers without large prime factors") showing one has $y$-smooth numbers in $[x,x+x^{0.99}]$ for $y=\exp((\log x)^{2/3+\epsilon})$. (1/2)



This has been improved by various authors, most recently by Younis ("Asymptotics for smooth numbers in short intervals"), who showed one can take $y=\exp(C(\log x)^{2/3}(\log \log x)^{4/3})$ and actually get an asymptotic result. Under RH, he showed one can take $y=(\log x)^K$ for some $K$. See Younis' paper and MO question 311584.


Nice. But what if one aims only for most intervals?

For intervals of length $x^{0.99}$ I am not sure there are results for 'most intervals' in the literature (that go beyond Younis' work). But I do not claim that there isn't potential to do something here.
